# C structure that ends with an asterisk

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I was looking at this [example](https://sahebg.github.io/computersceince/minimum-spanning-tree-Kruskal-algorithm-c-program-example/) and I found out that there is the declaration

```
struct edge
{
      int x;
      int y;
      int weight;
      struct edge *link;
}*front = NULL;
```

What does this actually mean? Is it possible to create a structure which is also a pointer with the name front and it NULL...?

Comment: The same syntax as `int* x;`. It's just that there is a `struct` type instead of `int`.

Comment: A `struct` is just another type of variable.  So, similar to `int *a = NULL;`, can be created as `struct name{...} *tag = NULL;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A struct is just another C type, as such, the variables it is used to define, may be created as normal instances, or pointers:

```
int a, *pA=NULL; //normal instance, pointer instance

struct edge
{
      int x;
      int y;
      int weight;
      struct edge *link;
}sEdge, *front = NULL; //normal instance, pointer instance
```

And, as with any pointer variable, needs to be pointed to owned memory before it can be safely used: (examples)

```
int main(void)
{

    // both variable types are handled the same way... 

    pA = &a; //point pointer variable to normal instance of `int a`
    front = &sEdge;//point pointer `front` to instance of 'struct edge'

    //allocate memory, resulting in assigned address with associated memory.
    pA = malloc(sizeof(*pA));
    front = malloc(sizeof(*front)); 
    ...
```

***EDIT*** *to answer question in comments:*
This small example throws no error or warning.  (Edit your question above, or better yet, post another question showing details of what you are seeing.)

```
struct edge
{
      int x;
      int y;
      int weight;
      struct edge *link;
}*front = '\0';

int main(void)
{
    struct edge tree[10];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in main() method the same program declares 'struct edge tree[10];' in which my compiler throws error 'array type has incomplete element type'. So how can initialize this variable?

Comment: For that we'd need to see more of your code; that doesn't happen with either a [minimal example from what you've said](https://godbolt.org/g/wE7pnj) or [the code shown in the linked blog post](https://godbolt.org/g/zT3a8D).

Comment: @VassilisDe - I have included exactly what you have described in an edit above, I get no compiler warnings or errors when I build using `C99` compiler rules.

Comment: maybe i'm not doing something right...i keep separate files for the interface and function implementations. I excluded from main the header file which declares the struct, but the compiler now complains about struct declarations called twice

Comment: @VassilisDe - Is the warning similar to:  _multiply defined symbol_?  If so, you do have it defined in more than one place.  Look up and use `extern` modifier to modify scope of variables.  `static` can also be used depending on what you need to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

It is *a pointer to a struct* and a *declaration* of a new type called `struct edge`.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, or strictly speaking wrong, since it's very clearly *also* a declaration of a new type called `struct edge`.

Comment: I thought this was "given" @unwind, I was wrong as the downvote suggests. Sorry. I updated the answer now, hope it improved, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that would put some more light, when you write:

```
struct edge
{
      int x;
      int y;
      int weight;
      struct edge *link;
};
```

You are saying: I'm creatig struct edge, which I will use to **define** objects of this struct by typing:

```
struct edge edgeObject;
```

But when you write:

```
struct edge
{
      int x;
      int y;
      int weight;
      struct edge *link;
} edgeObject;
```

You are saying: I'm creating struct edge and at the same time I'm **defining** edgeObject which is of type `struct edge`.
And this allows you to use that object directly as it is already defined:

```
edgeObject.x = 0;
```

So going back to your example you are saying: I'm creating structure edge and at the same I'm **defining** pointer to that struct `front` which is set to NULL.